# Print Highcharts in pdf format

Tags: php, pdf, highcharts

Is it possible to Print the highchart as a PDF using DOMPDF or any other PHP Html pdf generators?

Answer (score 1):

Version 2 of Highcharts includes PDF generation. The Highcharts client side will export an SVG string, and there will be server modules based on Batik that do the conversion to PDF. You can try it out at [Link](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/?prerelease=1.3).

This component will only convert the chart itself. If you want to convert the whole webpage or parts of it, check out the server library with the name of wkhtmltopdf (read WebKit HTML to PDF). It converts the charts too.

Answer (score 1):

Please familiarise yourself with the included exporing module and parameters which can be used http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at their [latest announcement](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts) about generating images on the server.

Once you save the images, you can add them to a pdf using libraries such as [tcpdf](http://www.tcpdf.org/)